# Changing the display value based on a row value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to display a value in a row in ng-repeat based on the value from the database. i wanted to do some thing like this displayed below

[image]

I wanted to display if value **T** for **TRAINER** and **M** for **MANAGER**. could you give me a simple and efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternaries in `{{ }}`

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <td>{{ data.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.value == 'T' ? 'TRAINER' : (data.value == 'M' ? 'MANAGER' : data.value) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easy if you are used ng-if

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list">
    <td>{{ item.number }}</td>
    <td ng-if="{{item.Role}} == 'TRAINER'">T</td>
    <td ng-if="{{item.Role}} == 'MANAGER'">M</td>
</tr>
```

code not tested. just scratch to get an idea...